# Transcendentality of Coleman integral

Tags: nt.number-theory, p-adic-analysis, transcendental-number-theory

I wonder if there's any work that considers the algebracity/transcendentality of Coleman integral (over $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$). The reason I think about this is because, for hyperelliptic curves, there are some theories about such things over $\mathbb{C}$. For example, the *period* integrals like
$$
\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^{3} - x}} = \frac{\Gamma(1/4)^{2}}{2^{3/2}\pi^{1/2}}
$$
is known to be transcendental by Siegel (see [here](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Eswc/aws/2008/08WaldschmidtSlides3.pdf)). In case of Coleman integral, it seems that the exact value of the integral is not the most interest of people, but its *nonzeroness* is much more important due to its relation to the rational points on curves. There are some explicit examples in [this](https://spectrum.library.concordia.ca/984074/1/Colo%CC%80_MSc_F2018.pdf) thesis and also in other papers, and the exact values of them seems to be out of interest.

Comment: There is a relation between Coleman integrals and non-critical values of p-adic zeta functions; and p-adic zeta values are known to be irrational over $\mathbb{Q}$ in some cases. See e.g. this beautiful paper of Calegari: https://doi.org/10.1155/IMRN.2005.1235. This is vastly weaker than what you asked for, but I thought I'd post it in case it's of interest.

Comment: Simple cases of Coleman integrals give the $p$-adic logarithms, $p$-adic elliptic logarithms, ... There is quite a bit of research on linear forms of such. In certain iterated integration, terms linked to $p$-adic height pairings appear. Apart from cm elliptic curves, the transcendence of these are unknown, but conjectured. Maybe you need to narrow down, which integrals you are interested in.